# Netbeans storedprocedure entities

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, netbeans

Is there a way to map results from MySQL stored procedures into classes?  I'm thinking something like the entity model features of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called JPA in Java. It is probably not a exact match for what you are looking for as it creates entities based on the tables.  You can generate classes in Netbeans based on the tables. You will then manipulate these classes to add new records, delete and update records from your database. It handles the SQL part for you. You can call stored procedures in JPA if you want to.

See this tutorial on it. http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-crud.html. JPA is a ORM or Object Relational Mapping tool. Hope that helps.

Comment: If I manually create a class, JPA can map the results of a storedprocedure call into a list of this class?

Comment: You can call a stored procedure and have it populate a list of objects with the results. Assume we have a class customer and you call a procedure proc_GetAllCustomersWithOverDuePayment if this stored procedure returns records that can be mapped to the customer class you will have a list of customer objects. So yes it can be done. JPA is quite a large specification so there is a lot of things  you can do but I am pretty sure it is what you are looking for.